lower bound for the hitting time
I was reading the book by Meyn and Tweedie(2009), and on page 87 there's an inequality i dont know where it comes from.
Here's the setup:
Let $P(x,A)$ denote a transition kernel of a markov chain $X_n$ on a general state space. $\tau_A=\inf\{n\geq 1: X_n \in A\}$ is the hitting time.
And there's the part I don't understand why:
For a set $A(m):=\{x: \sum_{n=1}^m P^n(x,A)\geq m^{-1}\}$, we have $P_x(\tau_A\leq m)\geq m^{-2}$.
I was trying to use Markov inequality but could not get the same result. Any suggestion is appreciated! Thanks!

Sorry, why would it be so? It seems to me $P_x(\tau_A\leq m) \leq \sum_{n=1}^m P^n(x,A)$, not the other way around.

Ah yes, my bad, I was too quick

We have $P_x( \tau_A \leq m) \geq \max_{n=1,...m} P^n(x,A)$ but since $x \in A$, we get
$$ \max_{n=1,...m} P^n(x,A) \geq \frac{1}{m} \sum_{n=1}^mP^n(x,A) \geq \frac{1}{m^2}$$

Ah! Ofc! $P_x\left(\cup_{n=1}^m {X_n \in A} \right) \geq \max_n P_x( X_n \in A)$. Thank you!

@Kryvtsov Glad to help, an upvote would be nice :)
